# How to use Keras pre-trained 'Embedding' layer?

Tags: text-mining, lstm, keras, word-embeddings

guys!
I've trained model in keras using Embedding on specific corpus of articles. 
I use this tutorial http://adventuresinmachinelearning.com/word2vec-keras-tutorial/

Now I want use it as layer in my LSTM. I found a lot of examples, how to load word2vec or glove, but no one discuss in connection with Keras.

As I understand i should load  and extract the embedding weights from the embedding layer and store it in a numpy array, ready for use in Keras.

But how can i make it?

I found some interesting thoughts here http://www.orbifold.net/default/2017/01/10/embedding-and-tokenizer-in-keras/

> There is much confusion about whether the Embedding in Keras is like
>   word2vec and how word2vec can be used together with Keras. I hope that
>   the simple example above has made clear that the Embedding class does
>   indeed map discrete labels (i.e. words) into a continuous vector
>   space. It should be just as clear that this embedding does not in any
>   way take the semantic similarity of the words into account. Check the
>   source code if want to see it even more clearly.

any clues?